# I'm looking for a good general use laptop with a few requirements

Tags: laptop

Maybe this isn't the best question to ask, but I am looking for recommendations.

I'm looking for a good general use laptop that needs to run Quickbooks and MS Office.  I'd like at least an i5 Intel proc, 8 GB of RAM, SSD would be nice but HDD is fine, and the kicker: 17.3" screen.  I'd like it to be priced around $1000 USD.

I've been browsing the major manufacturer sites (Dell, HP, Lenovo) but I haven't really found the best deal.  I have seen a couple that would fit, but I'd like some recommendations or alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Before buying an ASUS laptop, please read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160606135858/http://teletext.zaibatsutel.net/post/145370716258/deadupdate-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and) first.**
-Thanks [ArtOfCode](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/8/artofcode) for pointing this out.

ASUS makes good general use Laptops. I've owned an ASUS laptop a couple generations older than this one and had no issues other than the battery life left a lot to be desired.

Keyboard feels very solid (similar to a MacBook Pro).
Trackpad could be a little better but worked quite well.
Solid USB other connections. Not wiggly.

[image: Image courtesy of Newegg.com]

[ASUS X751LX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA9B53PV8864)

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths if you get this laptop, be sure to disable LiveUpdate: [it's a massive security risk](http://teletext.zaibatsutel.net/post/145370716258/deadupdate-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and).